# Solid JS equivalent of React.HTMLProps<...>

Tags: typescript, solid-js

I have a React component with prop types like:

```
type Props = React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement> & {
    to?: string;
};
```

How do you write the equivalent prop types in SolidJS? I tried this:

```
type Props = Component<HTMLAnchorElement> & {
    to?: string;
};
```

And it compiles, but it does not have the same built in props as the former such as `children`.

Comment: Did you mean to say "but it does *not* have the same" ?

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solid JS has `JSX.IntrinsicElements` which provides properties types indexed by tag name:

```js
import { JSX } from 'solid-js';

type Props = JSX.IntrinsicElements['a'] & {
    to?: string;
};
```

Comment: Dang, that took a lot of googling to find...

Comment: While this answer is not wrong, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74911993/927943 is more thorough and robust with respect to leveraging Typescript.

There's also a related discussion here: https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/970

Comment: @johnny as mentioned in that github discussion, `JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>` is not specific enough. If you need to access anchor-specific properties, you have to use specific type name: 
 `JSX.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>`.  `JSX.IntrinsicElements` provides uniform access by tag name, and `JSX.IntrinsicElements['a']`  is just a mapping to [JSX.AnchorHTMLAttributes](https://github.com/ryansolid/dom-expressions/blob/main/packages/dom-expressions/src/jsx.d.ts#L1958C8-L1958C47) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSX.HTMLAttributes<T>`:

```js
interface Props extends JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {}
```

This comes in handy when you need extend some element with additional properties like the way we do in React:

```js
export interface Props extends JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  value: Accessor<string>;
  onInput: JSX.EventHandler<HTMLInputElement, InputEvent>;
  icon?: HTMLImageElement;
  label?: HTMLImageElement,
}

const Input: Component<Props> = (props) => {
  const [_, ...rest] = splitProps(props,  ['icon', 'label']);

  const handleInput: JSX.EventHandlerUnion<HTMLInputElement, InputEvent> = (event) => {}

  return (
    <span class={style.wrapper}>
      {props.icon && props.icon}
      {props.label && props.label}
      <input {...rest} value={props.value()} onInput={handleInput} />
    </span>
  )
};
```

And for events you have to ways:

```js
 const handleInput: JSX.EventHandler<HTMLInputElement, InputEvent> = (event) => {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
};

const handleInput: JSX.EventHandlerUnion<HTMLInputElement, InputEvent> = (event) => {
  setValue(event.currentTarget.value);
};
```

Second one works because it as union:

```js
type JSX.EventHandlerUnion<T, E extends Event> = 
  | JSX.EventHandler<T, E>
  | JSX.BoundEventHandler<T, E>;
```